# How to make the output of this prolog program state "true"?

Tags: list, prolog, backtracking

I have this example prolog program, which on output prints a number of * corresponding to size of list elements.

```
bl([N|L]):-s(N),nl,bl(L).
s(N):-N>0,write(*),N1 is N-1,s(N1).
s(N):-N=<0.
```

For example, for the query `bl([1,1,2,6,24]).` the program outputs:

```
1 ?- bl([1,1,2,6,24]).
*
*
**
******
************************
false.
```

My task is to make the program give "true" as a final answer. If I am correct, it gives false, because when it finishes calling and printing * for the last element 24, prolog tries to match for the tail bl([]), which is now an empty list and starts backtracking. Therefore I tried to put a cut after the `nl`, but that did not work either. Any ideas why, or how to make it output true?

```
bl([N|L]):-s(N),nl,!,bl(L).
s(N):-N>0,write(*),N1 is N-1,s(N1).
s(N):-N=<0.
```

I don't really understand prolog or the concept of backtracking that well, so this was probably an ill-worded explanation and the logic behind my solution is most probably wrong as well. For that I am sorry.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: As @CapelliC points out briefly in his answer, your cut would have done what you were hoping, but you are missing a base success case for `bl/1`, namely, `bl([]).` Without it, even with the cut, `bl/1` recurses down to the empty list (`[]`) and then fails because `bl([]).` is false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could add `bl([]).`, or use maplist/2 and change slightly your program, since bl/1 it's really just a service predicate required to visit the list.

```
s(N):-N>0,write(*),N1 is N-1,s(N1).
s(N):-N=<0,nl.

bl(L) :- maplist(s, L).
```